# Question about a convergent sequence and inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose $0 < x < 1 $ and let $n > 0 $ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x < \frac{1}{n}$. If there exists a sequence $x_n \downarrow x$, then there exists $N$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x_n < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \geq N$

MY try:

Let $\epsilon = 1/n$ so we have and $N$ such that for all $n >N$,

$$ x - 1/n < x_n < x + 1/n $$

How can I bound this inequality to obtain the result?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a typo?

Comment: For $n=1, \frac{1}{2} \leq x < 1$ where as for $n=2, \frac{1}{3} \leq x < \frac{1}{2}.$ If by *"let $n >0$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x < \frac{1}{n}$"* you mean it's true for a fixed  $n,$ then please changed the notation (say $n_0$ or $M$). It's really confusing with all those $n$ with different meaning.

Comment: I am not sure where Szebo, but if $x$ is nonzero and $x_n\downarrow x$, then the conclusion cannot hold since it would make $x_n$ converge to zero.

Comment: @Krish Although it would be better to use different notation, it is obvious that for $x$ $n$ is fixed (since $\{[1/(n+1),1/n[\}_n$ are pairwise disjoint). :)

Comment: @Uzman: That was precisely my point. Not to use the same notation one as a fixed number and one as a variable. The first line of my above comments are for just to emphasis that point.

Comment: Yeah you're right, at least for OP's own sake it would have been better.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe in the conclusion the bounds are fixed to be the bounds for $x$?

Comment: This not-even-a-question whose author chooses to stay silent received *three* upvotes?

Comment: What about $\epsilon=\frac1n-x$?